# For integrable $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ show that the limit inferior of $\int_{k}^{k+1}|f| = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

> For integrable $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ show that the limit inferior of $\int_{k}^{k+1}|f| = 0$.

$f$ integrable implies that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| < \infty$$

and I want to show that $$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_{k}^{k+1} |f|  =0.$$

What I have is that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| = \int_{-\infty}^0 |f| + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} |f|$$ subtracting $\int_{-\infty}^0 |f|$ from both sides I end up with $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|- \int_{-\infty}^0 |f| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} |f| \implies \int_{0}^\infty |f| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} |f|.$$

This seems to make sense and now $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} |f| < \infty \implies \lim_{k\to \infty } \int_{k}^{k+1}|f| = 0$$  but the limit $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty |f| $$ doesn't seem to make sense since I don't have any $k$'s in here? What can I do to get the limit inferior here?

Comment: Where did you get the expression $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty} |f|$ from? Also, this still makes sense even when the term that you're taking the limit of is independent of $k$, since it can simply be considered as a constant sequence.

Comment: Taking the limit of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|- \int_{-\infty}^0 |f| = \int_{0}^\infty |f| = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} |f|  < \infty$. The rhs evaluates to $0$ so it would imply that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty |f|  = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Put $a_k =  \int_{k}^{k+1} |f| \ge 0$. We have
$$\infty > \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f| = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1} |f| = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} a_k = \sum_{k \ge 0} a_k + \sum_{k \ge 1} a_{-k}.$$
It follows that $\sum_{k \ge 0} a_k < \infty$ and $\sum_{k \ge 1} a_{-k}  < \infty$.
As $\sum_{k \ge 0} a_k $ is a convergent series then $a_k \to 0$ ($k \to +\infty$) (necessary condition). Also as $\sum_{k \ge 1} a_{-k}$  is a convergent series then $a_{-k} \to 0$ ($k \to +\infty$). Thus $a_k \to 0$  ($k \to \infty$).